# why double desity DWT use two HPF?

Tags: image-processing, denoising, dwt

The double-density DWT is an improvement upon the critically sampled DWT with important additional properties: It employs one scaling function and two distinct wavelets, which are designed to be offset from one another by one half,
I wonder why double density DWT uses two HPF with offset 1/2 insteed of one HPF in DWT?
what he mean with offset from one another by one half?
how it impoved the lack of shift invariance?